# Impact New Customers Every hour - Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, scheduled, scheduled-action, relatedlistnew

I have one Journey to send emails on Journey Builder and we want to evaluate the New Contacts in every Hour (on that Data Extension that comes from FTP). This is an No-reentry Journey.

So is available to impact the New Contacts from this way, on Journey builder:

1. Schedule > Recurring Schedule > Hourly: every 1 hours > End Never;
2. Contact Evaluation > Evaluate new record Only: Only new record added after Journey activation.

Is this the right process?
Or do I need to create an automatism?
Thank you

Comment: You do need to pull that data from FTP so you will need an automation for that

Comment: What is the best way to create that on Automation Studio?
Create a Workflow where the Starting Source is Schedule (every our) or File Drop (thought FTP), and the activitie is a SQL Query or other?

The process should be this: File Drop > Schedule every hour to evaluate the New Contacts every day every hour 

So what is the Staring Source and the others Steps?